# Zooming ONLY inside img in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

Is there any way to be able to zoom images inside divs without allowing the entire page to zoom?

Currently I'm using:

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

To disallow zooming, but then I really need to be able to zoom on images in the various views.

So is there any way to allow specific divs/imgs to be zoomable while disallowing zoom on the big page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). I've used it in PhoneGap to enable pinch zoom on specific divs and may work for your scenario.